# how to set the generated item for itemscontrol in databinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

if I'm using a ListBox for data binding, the listbox generates a listboxitem for each item, same goes for combo box and comboBoxItem. 
My question is - how do i set it myself for a given ItemsControl? (e.g. make the containing element be Border)?

Comment: [ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a little with ILSpy -

Apparently The magic is done in

```
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new ListBoxItem();
    }
```

This is where ListBox does it - and in my control I should override this as well.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right approach? A custom style seems less complex to me.

Comment: custom style is not enough in my situation. if you look at my question again you'll see this is what i asked for to begin with..

Comment: either i dont understand your question or you dont understand custom styles, i read it again (slowly) but havent changed opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The default item used to wrap each item is a `ContentPresenter`

I am not sure why you'd want to overwrite this, since it has no visual appearance or specific behavior that would mess with your UI.

You can set the `ItemTemplate` if you want to wrap each item in a `Border` object

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Or set the `ItemContainerStyle` if you want to apply any specific style to the `ContentPresenter`

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: +1 What would be the syntax for border in ItemsContainerSyle ?

Comment: @Blam `ContentPresenter` does not have any visual appearance at all, which includes not having a border element. It's simply a container object meant to hold content. If you want to give each item a `Border`, you need to wrap the item in a `Border` object, such as I have in the `ItemTemplate`. The default content is a TextBlock bound to the the object, although it's fairly common to overwrite that with something else.

Comment: that is not what i asked for.. Whenever u databind an itemscontrol, it generates a containing element for each item in the list. i wanted to REPLACE the containing element, not just ADD a border to contain my template.

Comment: @EladKatz Out of curiosity, why do you want to replace it?

Comment: for the same reason a listbox needs to replace it's items containers.. again - this is what i asked to begin with.